# Need to get the item, from the list view, with a custom adapter, and a context menu

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu, onitemclicklistener

I need to get for example the second patient in the list, it is always the first position and my int is always 0, there's no way to get the real position when I click any position, here is  my code:

```
public void setupGUI() {
    listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
    if (getIntent().getParcelableExtra(Constants.PARCELABLE_TAG) != null) {
        user = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(Constants.PARCELABLE_TAG);
        GetDoctor gd = new GetDoctor(DoctorMenu.this, user.getId(), user.getToken());
        gd.execute();


        if (user != null) {
            userToken = user.getToken();
            FillPatientsTask fpt = new FillPatientsTask(DoctorMenu.this, this, userToken, null);
            fpt.execute();

        } else {
            userToken = "";
            Toast.makeText(this, "User was null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            numberPatient = position;
        }
    });
    registerForContextMenu(listView);
}
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info =
            (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_patient_menu, menu);
    patient = items.get(numberPatient);
}
```

Comment: OnItemClickListener will not be called when Context Menu is opened. The clicked position can be obtained from menuInfo. Therefore add `numberPatient = info.position;` before `patient = items.get(numberPatient);` Hope that helps!

Comment: I'll try later, thnx!

Answer (score 0):

It will be ever `zero` why collections begin with first position as `0 position`. For your case, try as follow:

```
numberPatient = position + 1;
```

Comment: In that way, it shows array indexoutofbounds, if I press the object and then I show context menu, it is the object i pressed before, and when I get back the numberPatient is the same.

Comment: Maybe your `items` have not the same size of patients list

Comment: It comes from an AsyncTask from the server, I'll record a video and show you